# IComparer C# + generics

Tags: c#, generics, icomparer

How I can write make method Compare in RoomComparerByVolume ?
"Define a generic class RoomComparerByVolume<> implementing IComparer interface.
Impose a constraint on the type argument so that it should implement the IShape interface.
This comparer should perform comparison of rooms by room volume."

```
    public interface IShape 
    {
        public double Area()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public class Rectangle : IShape
    {
        public double Length { get; set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }
    
        public double Area()
        {
            return Length * Width;
        }
    }
    
    public class Trapezoid : IShape
    {
        public double Length1 { get; set; }
        public double Length2 { get; set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Area()
        { 
        return (Length1 + Length2) * Width / 2;
        }
    }
    
    public class Room<T> where T : IShape, ICloneable, IComparable
    {
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public T Floor;
    
        public double Volume()
        {
            return Height * Height;
        }
    
        public object Clone()
        {
            return new Room<T> { Height = this.Height, Floor = this.Floor };
        }
    
        public int CompareTo(object o)
        {
            Room<T> r = o as Room<T>;
            if (r != null)
                return this.Volume().CompareTo(r.Volume());
            else
                throw new Exception("Unable to compare");
        }
    }
    
    public class RoomComparerByVolume<T> : IComparer<T> where T : IShape
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: Don't really get your question seems `public class RoomComparerByVolume<T> : IComparer<T> where T : IShape` is already that what you are looking for.

Comment: This sound very much as an assignment. Exactly what do you have a problem understanding? Have you checked documentation for `IComparer<T>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear. If compare "by room *volume*" means in fact compare `Area()` values
and you want to imeplement a corresponding comparer, you can put something like this

```
public sealed class ShapeComparerByArea<T> : IComparer<T> where T : IShape
{
    public int Compare(T left, T right) 
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))         
            return 0;
        if (left == null)
            return 1;
        if (right == null)
            return -1;

        return left.Area().CompareTo(right.Area());     
    }        
}
```

If you want to define comparable `Room` class (which has `Shape` `Floor`) you can put it as

```
  public class Room : IComparable<Room> {
    public Room(IShape floor, double height) {
      Floor = floor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(floor));
      
      Height = height > 0 
        ? height 
        : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(height));
    }

    public IShape Floor { get; }

    public double Height { get; }

    public double Volume => Floor.Area() * Height;

    public int CompareTo(Room other) {
      if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        return 0;
      if (other is null)
        return 1;

      return Volume.CompareTo(other.Volume);
    }
  }
```

Finally, `RoomComparerByVolume` can be

```
  public sealed class RoomComparerByVolume : IComparer<Room> {
    public int Compare(Room left, Room right) {
      if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        return 0;
      if (left == null)
        return 1;
      if (right == null)
        return -1;

      return left.Volume.CompareTo(right.Volume);
    }
  }
```

Demo:

```
Room myRoom = new Room(
  new Trapezoid() { Length1 = 5, Length2 = 7, Width = 3}, 
  2.8);

Room myOtherRoom = new Room(
  new Rectangle() { Length = 3, Width = 4 }, 
  2.5);

Console.WriteLine(myRoom.CompareTo(myOtherRoom));

RoomComparerByVolume comparer = new RoomComparerByVolume();

Console.WriteLine(comparer.Compare(myRoom, myOtherRoom));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the desired declaration should look like

```
public class RoomComparerByVolume<T> : IComparer<Room<T>> where T : IShape, ICloneable, IComparable{
    public int Compare(Room<T> left, Room<T> right) {
        ...
    }
```

That way you can compare the two rooms. But note that the two rooms need to be the same shape using this method. Also note that you need to use the same generic constraints as you are using for `Room<T>`.

Also note that in many cases you do not need to create a specific comparer type. Often you can use a delegate to do the actual comparison:

```
Comparer<Room<Trapezoid>>.Create((l, r) => l.Volume().CompareTo(r.Volume));
```